# Authentication on Post DRF

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I got an error on my DRF. when I try to authenticate using a post method.

the token is the correct for the admin user. when I use a safe method it is sucessfull, but with the post method  no, it doesn't authenticate

my view

```
class SpecialistListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (OAuth2Authentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = Specialist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SpecialistSerializer
```

I don't understand why the status of the code returned is HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

It does'nt work on testing. I check that in postman is succesfull.

I'm using APIClient from rest_framework.test import APIClient

my test_client

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer EGsnU4Cz3Mx5bUCuLrc2hmup51sSGz')

class CreateSpecialist(APITestCase):
    fixtures = ['data','data2']
    def setUp(self):
        self.valid_payload = {
            'username': 'julia',
            'nick': 'julia',
            'password': 'intel12345',
            "first_name": "juliana",
            "last_name": "garzon"
        }

def test_create_specialist(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('specialists'),
        data=json.dumps(self.valid_payload),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just add the credentials before the post and it works! :D

```
def test_create_specialist(self):
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer EGsnU4Cz3Mx5bUCuLrc2hmup51sSGz')
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('specialists'),
        data=json.dumps(self.valid_payload),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```